# Jsoup java rewrites the file string which it should add

Tags: java, jsoup

code that should read html file and write the result another file the buffered writer writes the file but when the code is run with different urlit doesn't appends but rewrites the file and the previous content disappears

the solution recuired is that when jsoup iterates new html the result should add to output file and not rewrite

changed different writer types other than buffered writer

```
public class WriteFile 
{
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException
  { 
    String url = "http://www.someurl.com/registers";
    Document doc = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
    Elements es = doc.getElementsByClass("a_code");     

    for (Element clas : es) 
    {                    
      System.out.println(clas.text()); 
      BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("D://Author.html"));
      writer.append(clas.text());
      writer.close();
    } 
  }    
}
```

Comment: Why do you create new BufferedWriter in each iteration? Create one *before* loop, append text in loop, and close it after loop (preferably do it in try-with-resources which will close it for you automatically).

Comment: thancs that sounds good

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't mistake the [`append`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/Writer.html#append(java.lang.CharSequence))-method of the [`BufferedWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/BufferedWriter.html) as appending content to the file. It actually appends to the given writer.

To actually append additional content to the file you need to specify that when opening the file writer. [`FileWriter`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/io/FileWriter.html) has an additional constructor parameter allowing to specify that:

```
new FileWriter("D://Author.html", /* append = */ true)
```

You may even be interested in the [Java Files API](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/nio/file/Files.html) instead, so you can spare instantating your own `BufferedWriter`, etc.:

```
Files.write(Paths.get("D://Author.html"), clas.text().getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Your loop and what you are writing may further be simplifiable to something as follows (you may then even omit the `APPEND`-open option again, if that makes sense):

```
Files.write(Paths.get("D://Author.html"), 
            String.join("" /* or new line? */, 
                        doc.getElementsByClass("a_code")
                           .eachText()
                       ).getBytes(), 
            StandardOpenOption.CREATE, StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
```

Comment: thancs that was good Filewriter is an improvement on Buffered Writer and the try with resources happens automatically